# issue accessing field of an object in an array of object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, typescript, object, tags

I'm starting to develop a frontend for an application. For that I use react and I fetch the data in a React component. I manage to get my data and then I have to display it in my render. But I have two problems at this level.

To retrieve the data I have an interface of this type :

```js
export interface MyData {
    data1:            string | undefined;
    data2: number | undefined;
    specificDataArray:       SpecificData[] | undefined;
    data4:            OtherSpecificType | undefined;
}

export interface SpecificData {
    specificData1: string;
    specificData2: Date;
    ...
}

export interface OtherSpecificType {
    processed:         number;
    ....
}
```

My React component is the following (The return in render tries to represent the data as a JSON visually.):

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { MyData } from "../../interface/Interface"

interface IProps {
}

interface IState {
  logLoading: boolean | undefined,
  currentTestLog: MyData | undefined
}

const URL_FETCH_LOG = '...';

export default class Home extends React.Component <IProps, IState> {
  constructor (props: IProps){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      logLoading: true,

      currentTestLog: {
        data1: undefined,
        data2: undefined,
        specificDataArray: undefined,
        data4: undefined
      }
    };
  }

  fetchData = () => {
    this.setState({ logLoading: true });
    Axios.get<SoftSessionData>(URL_FETCH_LOG)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status === 200 && res != null) {

          this.setState({ currentTestLog:{... res.data} });

          console.log(res.data);  //OK
          console.log(this.state.currentTestLog);  //OK
          console.log(this?.state?.currentTestLog?.lookupKeys);  //OK
          console.log(this?.state?.currentTestLog?.lookupKeys?.length);  //OK

         console.log(this?.state?.currentTestLog?.lookupKeys?[0]);  //NOT OK error:  Property 'specificData1' does not exist on type 'number[]'.ts(2339)

          console.log(this?.state?.currentTestLog?.lookupKeys?[0].specificData1);  //NOT OK error:  ':' expected.ts(1005)
          
          this.setState({ logLoading: false });
        } else {
          console.log('problem when fetching logs');
                }
        })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>
          <button onClick={this.fetchData}>Search logs</button>
        </div>

        {this.state.logLoading == true ? <div>Waiting</div>:
          
          <div>
            <p>Test logs :</p>
            <br/>
            <div>
              <pre>   // NOT OK error: (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.pre: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLPreElement>, HTMLPreElement>
//This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)
                &lang;
                <br/>
                &nbsp; data1: <b>{this?.state?.currentTestLog?.data1} ,</b>   //OK
                <br/>
                &nbsp; data2: <b>{this?.state?.currentTestLog?.data2} ,</b>   //OK
                <br/>
                &nbsp; specificDataArray: &lceil;
                <br/>
                {this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray !== undefined ?   //OK
                  (
                    this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray?.map((i,index) => {
                      <div>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; index specificDataArray: {index} &lang;
                        <br/>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; specificData1: <b>{this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray?[index].specificData1} ,</b>    // NOT OK
                        <br/>
                        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; specificData2: <b>{this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray?.specificData2} ,</b>    // NOT OK
                        <br/>
                      </div>
                    })
                  ) : 
                  <div>&nbsp; &nbsp; no data found</div> 
                }
                <br/>
                &nbsp; &rfloor; ,
                <br/>
                &nbsp; data4: &lang;
                <br/>
                &nbsp; &nbsp; processed: <b>{this?.state?.currentTestLog?.data4?.processed} ,</b>       //OK
                ...
                <br/>
                &nbsp; &rang; ,
                <br/>
                &rang;
              </pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Shape of my MyData data when I display it in the web console after fetching it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o19an.png)

The two problems are therefore the following:

How to access the data of one of the objects in the specificDataArray in MyData since `this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray?[index].specificData1` does not work, it returns the following error?

And why the tag surrounding my return in the render (here the pre tag but if I remove it it will be the div tag ) is returning this error when I insert a state mapping in the render: (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.pre: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes, HTMLPreElement>
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746)
When I remove the mapping from one of my state from the render this error disappears.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: To make an indexed access on an array that might be `undefined`, the syntax is `someArray?.[someIndex]`. Notice the `.` character between `?` and `[`. So, in your case: `this?.state?.currentTestLog?.specificDataArray?.[index].specificData1`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#array_item_access_with_optional_chaining) for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was indeed a syntax problem.

However, I still have this error on my HTML tag which contains the rest of my tags: (property) JSX.IntrinsicElements.pre: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLPreElement>, HTMLPreElement>
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects a single child of type 'ReactNode', but multiple children were provided.ts(2746).

This error appears on the parent HTML tag only when I browse with a .map one of my state array inside the parent tag, Do you have any idea what it might be ?

Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: My bad, I finally understand it, I had to change my brace after my map to brackets to get an implicit return :)

Comment: Try to stick to a single enquiry per question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts